# How to transfer data to and from Azure File Share more efficiently

Tags: azure, file-sharing

I'm wanting to use Azure File Share to share data files with several Virtual Machines, which then take said data and run tools/programs and jobs using the data. As of now when trying this it seems that data access and transfers (which these jobs necessitate) is extremely slow. When running these tools on local data there isn't this issue.

Am I using Azure File share wrong or missing something?

Answer (score 0):

First off, you cannot compare running data operations locally to running them on any sort of remote file share, there is a big new component in the way, the network. Operations on a network share will always be slower than local, the speed of light sees to that at a minimum. You don't mention how much data you are trying to move about, but obviously, this will impact things as well

Secondly, Azure file shares are not particularly fast, the default throughput is at most 60MB/s. If you need faster throughput then you can look at premium Azure Files, this is in preview currently and increases throughput to around 600MB/s.

You also want to make sure that [accelerated networking](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/create-vm-accelerated-networking-cli) is enabled on your VMs to ensure you get the best network throughput.